# JQuery different dialog don't distinct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dialog

I have 1 dialog, but there must be 2 different actions(Saving and Editing). Based on this, different dialogs should show up and different actions actions will happen. I decided to solve this issue using JQuery
like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var dialogEditPartDiv = $('#dialogPart'); // For editing
  var dialogAddPartDiv = $('#dialogPart'); // For saving
  
  $('#addButton').click(function() 
  {
  dialogAddPartDiv.dialog('open');
  });
  
  dialogAddPartDiv.dialog(
  {
 autoOpen: false,
 modal: true,
 buttons:
 {
  'Save part' : function(){}
 },
 beforeClose : function(event) 
 {
  if(!confirm("The part won't be saved. Continue?"))
  {
  return false;
  }
  else 
  {
   
  }
 }
  });
  
  
  $('#editButton').click(function() 
  {
   dialogEditPartDiv.dialog('open');
  });
  
  dialogEditPartDiv.dialog(
  {
 autoOpen: false,
 modal: true,
 buttons:
 {
  'Save changes' : function(){}
 },
 beforeClose : function(event) 
 {
  if(!confirm("Your changes won't be saved. Continue?"))
  {
  return false;
  }
  else 
  {
  
  }
 }
  });

});
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    <button id="addButton"> +Add </button>
    <button id="editButton"> Edit </button>

    <div id="dialogPart">

    <table>

    <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" size="80" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" size="80" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="65" value=""></td>
    </tr>

    </table>

    </div>
    </body>
```

But it doesn't work the way it's expected. Now, "Add" button is ignored and always shows up "Editing" dialog. Why?

Comment: You are calling the same dialog with both buttons.

Comment: Providing a JS fiddle for this would help the community is addressing this question.

Comment: It works fine https://jsfiddle.net/Liamm12/6extvdbm/ where's the problem?

Comment: When you click "Add" "Edit" dialog is opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the same dialog every time, you need to make each one unique. [I went to the documentation here](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/), bottom of the page, and I have created two dialogs in the attached code, run it to see how it works, then you can apply this to your code.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>dialog demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">I'm a dialog</div>

<button id="opener2">open the dialog2</button>
<div id="dialog2" title="Dialog Title">I'm a dialog2</div>
 
<script>
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});

$( "#dialog2" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#opener2" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog2" ).dialog( "open" );
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But what if the dialogs are different only in their buttons functions? Should I create 2 absolute same dialogs which named differently and later specify buttons functions? It's just like copypaste

Comment: Yes, unless you want to write some logic based on the button that's clicked, but in this case that might be overkill.